# Get colors of segments from already plotted sequential colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I need to create a new colorbar with `branca` on the basis on an already plotted colorbar in `matplotlib`.

The object I have is of the following type:

```
<matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar object at 0x7f089252e790>
```

It stems from a classic colorbar plotting in `matplotlib` like so:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(filled_contours, extend=extend, cax=cax)
```

Certain attributes could be found playing in the console (VS Code integrated):

```
In: cbar.values
Out: array([0.00099944, 0.00205833, 0.00311722, 0.00417611, 0.005235  ,
       0.00629389, 0.00735278, 0.00841167, 0.00947056])

In: cbar._y
Out: array([0.        , 0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.44444444,
       0.55555556, 0.66666667, 0.77777778, 0.88888889, 1.        ])

In: cbar.cmap.name
Out: 'Reds'

In: cbar.cmap
Out: <matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap object at 0x7f08b1d91910>
```

I couldn't figure out though, where to extract the colors used in each segment of the already plotted cbar.

As a workaround, I came up with the following code piece, even though I'm not entirely sure if these are exactly the same colors I see in the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
extracted_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(cbar.cmap.name)
extracted_colors = [extracted_cmap(v) for v in cbar._y]
```

`print(extracted_colors)` delivers the employed colors (as I suppose):

```
[(1.0, 0.9607843137254902, 0.9411764705882353, 1.0), (0.996555171088043, 0.8884429065743944, 0.8378316032295271, 1.0), (0.9901422529796232, 0.7686120722798924, 0.6780930411380238, 1.0), (0.9882352941176471, 0.6261437908496732, 0.5084967320261438, 1.0), (0.9860976547481738, 0.48704344482891193, 0.3615532487504806, 1.0), (0.9629065743944636, 0.331841599384852, 0.23667820069204154, 1.0), (0.8901960784313725, 0.18562091503267975, 0.15294117647058825, 1.0), (0.7598462129950019, 0.0855363321799308, 0.10609765474817377, 1.0), (0.6175009611687813, 0.05167243367935409, 0.07853902345251824, 1.0), (0.403921568627451, 0.0, 0.05098039215686274, 1.0)]
```

When finally creating the colorbar via `branca` based on the above-mentioned workaround it seems like the correct colors are being depicted.

Nevertheless, I believe it must be possible to retrieve them directly from the cbar-object instead of having to regenerate them on my own.
I guess I just didn't find the right sub-sub-...attribute of the `matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar object`.